# How to make Excel columns read-only but re-sizable in EPPlus C# ?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, epplus, epplus-4

In my MVC project, users can select some products in the UI and download the related product information in Excel (.xlsx) format.

Our business requirements is, apart from few columns/cells the file should be read-only. I'm using `EPPlus 4.0.4` to generate the Excel, and it's working great so far.

The issues I'm facing here is, the moment I make the worksheet protected, user cannot re-size the columns anymore (dragging the header to change column width). So, texts in some columns are not visible completely. To fix that, I made them AutoFit (## in code below). So, texts are visible now. But still, user cannot change the column widths which they should be able to.

So my questions is, can I make the cells/columns read-only but make them re-sizable like normal Excel?

My code below

```
//using OfficeOpenXml;
//using OfficeOpenXml.Style;
private void ProtectExcel(ExcelWorksheet ws, int columnCount)
{
    ws.Protection.AllowSort = true;
    ws.Protection.AllowSelectUnlockedCells = true;
    ws.Protection.AllowAutoFilter = true;

    for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++)
    {
        ws.Column(i).Style.Locked = true; //making read-only
        ws.Column(i).AutoFit(); //## showing all text
    }

    ws.Protection.IsProtected = true; //making the sheet protected 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many properties on the `ws.Protection` property to specify what will be protected. One is `AllowFormatColumns`, so:

```
ws.Protection.AllowFormatColumns = true;
```